# Azure SQL Design Recommendation

Tags: database, azure, database-design, azure-sql-database

I have use case where I have a job which insert around 30 million rows every hour. It's kind of snapshot we are taking for some data source and we are intersted only on the latest snapshot for reporting purpose, so once the new snapshot data comes so old snapshot data become useless to us as reporting will be based on new Snapshot row. We have field called `last_updated_timestamp` which is a flag to determine latest data so all rows in one job will have same timestamp and we are taking `max(last_updated_timestamp)` for our reporting needs.

We need to store data for 20 days only and all our 99% queries will have fixed format so our queries will look like this:

```
select * from our_table where store_id = <>, dep_id = <> schedule_day <> and last_updated_timestamp = (max value which is present for that schedule_day for store_id and dep_id)
```

**My Approach:**

Is to create `clustered index on store_id, dep_id, schedule_day, last_updated_timestamp` so my queires will be very fast.
For deleting the old snapshot how i should do? Will it lead to index fragmentation?

schedule_day and last_updated_timestamp values are always increasing. Each job insert the data for present day and future 3 days no past data is inserted.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is Creating a clustered index on the columns store_id, dep_id, schedule_day, and last_updated_timestamp is a good way.
Because this will help when you are a filtering on these columns.

And for deleting the old snapshot data as you mentioned that data become useless for reporting and will be done based on new Snapshot row.

I have tried it at my end. I have created a Table Daily_table001.With below schema.

```
CREATE TABLE Daily_table001 (
    id INT ,
    data VARCHAR(255),
    last_updated_timestamp DATETIME,
    schedule_day DATE
);
```

There are 23 Records in the table. With the schedule_day and last_updated_timestamp Columns.

[image]
Created Clustred Index for id, last_updated_timestamp. Selecting columns and Grouping By.

[image]

For deleting the old snapshot I have inserted 2 new rows into the table and deleting the old records using the below query.

```
Insert into Daily_table001 values
 (24, 'Data 1', '2023-05-30 12:00:00', '2023-05-30'),
    (25, 'Data 2', '2023-05-30 12:00:00', '2023-05-30')
```

[image]
Now using the Delete Query we will delete the Old Snapshot and will insert the new records that has the new last_updated_timestamp and schedule_day i.e 30.

```
DELETE FROM Daily_table001
WHERE last_updated_timestamp < (
    SELECT MAX(last_updated_timestamp)
    FROM Daily_table001
);
```

The above query will specifies that rows with a "last_updated_timestamp" value less than the maximum "last_updated_timestamp" value in the entire table should be deleted.

[image]

[image]

As the Above Delete query will delete the Old records and New records will be inserted.

And also to aviod the index fragmentation when executing the DELETE statement in SQL Server. you Can Specify a fill factor